# How can i use code from other pages into current page?

Tags: php, search, helper, code

a question what can be useful to know is
how to use code from other pages into the current page you
are working on?

e.g. I want to echo the total product count of the search query on
list.phtml

Currently the product count is used in the pager/toolbar.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
```

Now when i try this in list.phtml it's not working.
 How can i get that to work?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\catalog.xml`

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
```

is a child block of

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

So, if you want to call `getTotalNum()` which is the method of `catalog/product_list_toolbar` block. You just need to get its child block `product_list_toolbar` and call the method.

```
$this->getChild('product_list_toolbar')->getTotalNum();
```

From other point of view, if you just need to get amount of products in `list.phtml` you can get it in this way:

```
$_productCollection->count()
```